# Inline all html tags with appropriate style from a stylesheet using html-inline-css-webpack-plugin

Tags: html, css, webpack, sass, inline

In order to send email from an application I develop, due to smtp client restrictions,
I would like to inline every style class from my CSS in each tags in my final html template using Webpack. In my case I can inline all the stylesheet in the one  div but my aim is to get every tag of the style to be filled with the appropriate style.

Here is my webpack.config :

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HTMLInlineCSSWebpackPlugin = require("html-inline-css-webpack-plugin").default;


module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: [
        './src/main.js',
    ],
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '[name].css',
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'review.html',
            template: './src/templates/models/review.pug',
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'access_request.html',
            template: './src/templates/models/domain_access_request.pug',
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'analytics_alert.html',
            template: './src/templates/models/analytics_alert.pug',
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'battery_pb.html',
            template: './src/templates/models/battery_pb.pug',
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'deco_module_cloud.html',
            template: './src/templates/models/deco_module_cloud.pug',
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'stock_pb.html',
            template: './src/templates/models/stock_pb.pug',
        }),
        new HTMLInlineCSSWebpackPlugin({
            replace: {
                target: 'tbody',
                removeTarget:true
            }
        }),

    ],
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.scss$/i,
          use: [
              MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
              loader: 'css-loader',
          },
            {
                loader: 'sass-loader'
            }
          ],
        },
          {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: [
              MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
              {
              loader: 'css-loader',
                  options: {
                      sourceMap: true,
                      minimize: true,
                      includePaths: [
                          path.resolve(__dirname, './src/templates/assets/scss')
                      ]
                  }
              },
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.pug$/,
          use: [
            'pug-loader'
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
          use: [
            'file-loader',
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
};
```

Hope you understood my issue.